# is local WSDL still needed after WSImport?

Tags: java, soap, wsimport

I have a local wsdl file, my question is that:  once i use wsimport to generate the java source files( *.java)  and relocate them into my existing project to use,  do I still need that wsdl file(assuming wsdl will never change)?   My assumption is that it is no longer needed as absolutely everything i need are already transferred to the  *.java?

Answer (score 0):

Once code generation happens (generate-sources or any other custom lifecycle task) the invocation will happen at runtime based on the endpoint on the WSDL. You do not require that file otherwise. When you have a code promotion , you either have a choice to just package the generated code and use that as a dependency (if you dont want to check in generated code) or run the lifecycle task everytime to generate the code in which case you can have the WSDL on resources location or point to the location of the WSDL (on HTTP)

Comment: Thanks, From your answer it sounds like I need it?(but I thought all URL +endpoints were transferred to the *.java?). Basically I have a wsdl on my desktop 2) I used wsimport to generate *.java files from it 3) I relocated the *.java into my existing project. so I want to know if I need to have the wsdl in my project also or I can disregard it?

Answer (score 0):

if you use SOAP, try using the tag `soa:address`, which you can set to the remote service's WSDL file location:

[image]